# Is there something like module.export in java?

Tags: java, module

I am searching for a possibility to import a function from a file path, like I can do in Javascript with [ES6 Modules / Imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import). I heard there would be something similar in Java8, is that right?

Comment: You mean like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Module_System ? But It will be available from Java 9!

Comment: Probably, I meant that :) Please post it as an answer :)

Comment: I don’t think that there will ever be support for importing something *from a file path*, as file paths are off programming language. That request doesn’t make much sense for Java anyway, as it has, unlike JavaScript, a clear separation between compile-time and runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Module_System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Module_System) ? But It will be available from Java 9!